# Parameter change call a function React js react-map-gl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl

I am new to React js. I am having a problem with calling a function when a parameter changes from the parent component without onClick function.

```
<div id="mapBox">
    <MapGL
     {...viewport}
     {...settings}
     mapStyle="mapbox://styles/XXXXX"
     onViewportChange={this._onViewportChange}
     dragToRotate={false}
     mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
     onChange = {this._goToViewport}>
 </MapGL>
 <button onClick={this._goToViewport}>
   {this.props.campus}
 </button>
```

For now, I did with onClick function. Is there any way to do without onClick function?

Comment: if you mean that something changes, in the props coming down from the parent and as a result of that change, you want to call a function, then look into componentDidUpdate or componentWillUpdate.

Comment: But It will cause a Maximum update depth exceeded error. Could I do it another way?

Comment: That depends; you haven't explain what the function does? I assume from the depth issue that it would change the state?

Comment: Also please give more details about how "the parameter changes from the parent" - how does it change?

Comment: _goToNewView = () => {
      const viewport = {...this.state.viewport, longitude: 1, latitude: 1};
      this.setState({viewport});
    }  It will setState of a new viewport, and parameter come from a form submit from parent @ChrisCousins

Comment: @ChrisCousins I got it! Thanks for your HELPPPP

Comment: Please post here what your solution was; that will help others.

Comment: It about check set if condition clearly in the componentDidUpdate!